# iframe in Firefox it is empty with aspx page

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iframe

I created a simple example where I call an ASP.NET page from an iframe. It works in Edge, Safari, Chrome and Opera but in FireFox the iframe is empty.
This is the test link:
https://www.pensa10.it/labs/TestIframe.aspx

In the FireFox console I see no error!!

The test PC is Windows 10, the FireFox version is FireFox Quantum 69.0.2 (32 bit).
If the iframe src is an html page no error. This is the second test link:
https://www.pensa10.it/labs/TestIframe2.aspx

These are the sources used.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Nota: come alternativa alla modifica manuale del file, è possibile utilizzare lo 
    strumento di amministrazione Web per configurare le impostazioni dell'applicazione. Utilizzare il comando 
    Configurazione ASP.NET del menu Sito Web di Visual Studio.
    Un elenco completo di impostazioni e commenti è disponibile nel file 
    machine.config.comments che si trova in genere in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Impostare compilation debug="true" per inserire i 
            simboli di debug nella pagina compilata. Poiché tale
            operazione ha effetto sulle prestazioni, impostare questo valore su true 
            solo durante lo sviluppo.
        -->

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            La sezione <authentication> consente di configurare 
            la modalità di autenticazione della sicurezza utilizzata da 
            ASP.NET per identificare un utente in ingresso. 
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    -->
    <!--
            La sezione <customErrors> consente di configurare 
            l'operazione da eseguire in caso di errore non gestito 
            durante l'esecuzione di una richiesta. In particolare, 
            consente agli sviluppatori di configurare le pagine di errore HTML 
            in modo che vengano visualizzate al posto dell'analisi dello stack dell'errore.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        La sezione system.webServer è richiesta per eseguire ASP.NET AJAX in Internet
        Information Services 7.0. Non è necessaria per la versione precedente di IIS.
    -->
</configuration>
```

**TestIframe.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestIframe.aspx.cs" Inherits="App_TestIframe" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Test iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Test iframe</h2>
<div class="container">
<div style="width:100%;height:1000px">
<iframe src="https://www.pensa10.it/labs/SimplePage.aspx" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**TestIframe.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class App_TestIframe : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
}
```

**SimplePage.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SimplePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="App_SimplePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Test iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Salve mondo da ASP.NET!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**SimplePage.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class App_SimplePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Custom-Header");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Also, please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: Have you tried the src with just a file name `<iframe src="SimplePage.aspx"></iframe>`? Just a thought.